# как исправить ошибку × TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null

Tags: javascript

```
 <text name="text1" id="text1">asxacasc</text>
 <Button size="xl" level="2" onClick={tern()}>
            ОТПРАВИТЬ ЗАЯВКУ
                </Button>
    </Panel>

);
function tern() {
    try {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {



            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var el = document.getElementById("text1");
                el.firstChild.data = "Unlock";
            }
            else {
                var el = document.getElementById("text1");
                el.firstChild.data = "lock";
            }




        };
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://cvetyservervk.000webhostapp.com/test.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send({ method: "proverka", addres: "asdasd" });


}

Persik.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    go: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};


export default Pro;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null

Явно говорит о том, что у вас `document.getElementById("text1")` возвращает `null`. Это говорит о том, что на странице нет элемента с `id` равным `text1`.

Comment: спасибо сейчас попробую исправить

Comment: <text name="text1" id="text1">asxacasc</text>
        <Button size="xl" level="2" onClick={tern()}>
            ОТПРАВИТЬ ЗАЯВКУ
    </Button>
    </Panel>

);
function tern() {
    try {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var el = document.getElementById("text1");


            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               
                el.firstChild.data = "Unlock";
            }
            else {

Comment: el.firstChild.data = "lock";
            }




        };
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://cvetyservervk.000webhostapp.com/test.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send({ method: "proverka", token: "asdasdassssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssddddddddddddddddddddddddddddaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" });

   
}

Persik.propTypes = {
 id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
 go: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};


export default Persik;

Comment: как все так  исправить?

Comment: @DanikOff а `text` - это что за компонент? Что-то реактовское? Я такого элемента в html не помнию. Знаю `input` и `textarea` только.